# how to open selected files through the default application of the file in VB 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I have Windows application written in VB 2010.Here, user may select any file from open dialog.So, I want to open the file in corresponding application.for example, suppose user selecting docx file then i have to open the file using msword,suppose,if it is a pdf file, then i have to open with adobe reader or available pdf reader(default application).

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

now with openfiledialog

```
Dim OpenFileDlg as new OpenFileDialog.

OpenFileDlg.FileName = "" ' Default file name
OpenFileDlg.DefaultExt = ".xlsx" ' Default file extension
OpenFileDlg.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.XLSX)|*.XLSX"
OpenFileDlg.Multiselect = True
OpenFileDlg.RestoreDirectory = True
' Show open file dialog box
Dim result? As Boolean = OpenFileDlg.ShowDialog()

' Process open file dialog box results
for each path in OpenFileDlg.Filenames
    Try
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to load the file. Maybe it was deleted?")
    End Try
    If result = True Then
        ' Open document
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
next
```

This will work if the file is registered with the OS. Use Try catch because it can throw errors if the file is in use.

**Edit:** It uses always the default application.

Comment: Is this possible to raise openwith dialog box?

Comment: @Chrisian Sauer : Please see my comment... Thanks for your effort

Comment: Basically, you need to load a OpenFileDialog, this is the standard windows control to open a filedialog. This dialog has a bunch of properties, a few of them are used in my example.
If you use wpf, acessing the Openfiledialog needs a reference to windows.forms

Comment: :I am not saying that Open file dialog...I meant it is like a OpenWith Windows dialog box for selecting appropriate exe for open the selected file....

Comment: I am also found the answer :Shell("rundll32.exe shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL " & path);

Comment: Shell is not as easy to debug as my solution, so I would recommed mine ;

Answer (score 13):

`Shell` and the Windows API `CreateProcess()` are for starting executable files.
If you're loading a document/file then these are handled by `ShellExecute()` and can be initiated in .NET using the `Process.UseShellExecute` property:

```
Private Function ShellExecute(ByVal File As String) As Boolean
  Dim myProcess As New Process
  myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = File
  myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
  myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
  myProcess.Start()
  myProcess.Dispose()
End Function
```

Taken from [the #VB wiki](http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/index.php/ShellExecute#VB.NET).