# Open .txt file from 'Windows Explorer' using 'Open With...'

Tags: vb.net

How to open a *.txt file using "Open with...", using this code?

```
Dim FileName As New System.IO.StreamReader(<Filename using Open With...>)
RichTextBox1.Text = FileName.ReadToEnd()
FileName.Close()
```

gets the filename of Open with...
How to get ?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select the file? If so I'd suggest looking into this link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778249/how-to-open-selected-files-through-the-default-application-of-the-file-in-vb-201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CommandLineArgs:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count > 0 Then
        '<FileName from OpenWith...> gets in first Command Args
        'Windows Explorer sends FileName to CommandLineArgs(0) value
        Dim FileNameOpenWith As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)
        Dim ReaderSystem As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileNameOpenWith)
        RichTextBox1.Text = ReaderSystem.ReadToEnd()
        ReaderSystem.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```