# How to create and open a file document

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, console-application

I have the following method/procedure

```
Private Sub CreateFile(ByVal filename As String, ByVal directory As String, ByVal extension As String)

    Dim file2create = directory & filename & extension
    Console.WriteLine(file2create)
    If (Not File.Exists(file2create)) Then
        File.Create(file2create)
    Else
        File.Open(file2create, FileMode.Open)
    End If
    console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

This code successfully creates a file but fails to open it, and just to say, I've checked other answers with similar questions but said answers haven't solved my problem, what I'm I doing wrong here. Thanks

================================UPDATE====================================

Thanks for the answers guys, but the file isn't opening. Just to clarify, when I say open, I mean thesame act as physically going to the file and clicking it.

If i were to use this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778249/how-to-open-selected-files-through-the-default-application-of-the-file-in-vb-201)

```
   Private Function ShellExecute(ByVal File As String) As Boolean

      Dim myProcess As New Process
      myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = File
      myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
      myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
      myProcess.Start()
      myProcess.Dispose()

    End Function
```

the file would successfully open, but if I were to use file.open() the file would not open, so in essence, I'm looking to create and then open a file in the same manner the above code does

Comment: Don't you just want to move the `File.Open` outside the if statement?

Comment: Or replace the whole if statement with `File.Open(file2create, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)`.

Comment: Both `File.Create()` and `File.Open()` return a `FileStream` which will lock the file from being accessed by other code/processes. Is that what you want or do you intend to actually read from/write to it using this code? Otherwise you should dispose of the stream: `File.Open(file2create, FileMode.OpenOrCreate).Dispose()`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed if you could post an updated version of the OPs code as an answer, I'll certainly +1 it in preference to other current answers

Comment: @DavidWilson, no problem!

Comment: you said to the compiler "create file if its not exists else open it" . So it opens the file if its exists and not opens it if its not existed. Write file.open command outside the if statement.

Comment: So you dont want to have your program interact with the file, you want to open the file in the program associated with the extension.

Comment: Oh. So you wanted to _execute_ the file or its associated application, well then the code you already found should do the trick. `File.Open()` doesn't _execute_ the file, but opens a [**`FileStream`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) so that you can _read data from it_, which is why it didn't work like you thought it would. :)

Comment: Though you can replace that entire `ShellExecute()` function with a single call: `Process.Start(file2create)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `File.Open` after the `IF..Then` block.

Here:

```
 Private Sub CreateFile(ByVal filename As String, ByVal directory As String, ByVal extension As String)
    Dim file2create = directory & filename & extension
    Console.WriteLine(file2create)
    If (Not File.Exists(file2create)) Then
        File.Create(file2create)
    End If
   'if file exits then open the file
If System.IO.File.Exists(file2create) = True Then
    Process.Start(file2create)
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if I do that, I get this error----> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\jamisco\Documents\jbiadfsdipa.txt' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: wait, you mean literally open the file? lol okay. see my updated answer

Comment: I'm now questioning my definition of open

Comment: see my answer now

Answer (score 3):

Here's the correct way to create a file if it doesn't exist, and then open it using `File.Open` method, which returns a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) object:

```
Private Sub OpenOrCreateFile(ByVal filename As String, ByVal directory As String, ByVal extension As String)
    'Use `Path.Combine` so you don't have to worry if the
    'directory path ends with a "\" or not.
    Dim file2create = Path.Combine(directory, filename) & extension
    Console.WriteLine(file2create)

    'Use a `Using` statement to make sure the FileStream object gets
    'disposed, and to prevent the file from staying locked after
    'finishing what you want to do with it.
    Using fs As FileStream = File.Open(file2create, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        'I'm not sure what you'd like to do after opening the file,
        'but now you have a `FileStream` object which you can use
        'to write bytes to the file (i.e. using `fs.Write()`).
    End Using

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

If you simply want to create a file, and write some text to it *overwriting existing contents*, you can just use:

```
File.WriteAllText(file2create, "SomethingToWrite")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's how it should be done. Thanks. Looking at your code i also learned something .. Path.Combine. Going away now to update lots of code with that.